# NSDictionary initWithContentsOfFile memory leak issue

Tags: ios, memory-leaks

I am using static analyser to check the memory leak of my code and I found the following part has potential leaks.

```
NSString *path = nil;
NSString *tutorialPath = nil;
if (CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR() == 2)
{
    path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sheetObjects-hd" ofType:@"plist"];
    tutorialPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sheetTutorial-hd" ofType:@"plist"];
} else
{
    path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sheetObjects" ofType:@"plist"];
    tutorialPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sheetTutorial" ofType:@"plist"];
}

_animDataDictionary = [[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path] objectForKey:@"frames"];
_tutorialAnimDataDictionary = [[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:tutorialPath] objectForKey:@"frames"];
```

The problem was with these two lines:

```
_animDataDictionary = [[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path] objectForKey:@"frames"];
_tutorialAnimDataDictionary = [[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:tutorialPath] objectForKey:@"frames"];
```

I've checked my dealloc code and I am pretty sure they are dealloced properly.

And this is how I defined the instances:

```
NSDictionary *_animDataDictionary;
NSDictionary *_tutorialAnimDataDictionary;
```

dealloc functions:

```
[_animDataDictionary release];
_animDataDictionary = nil;
[_tutorialAnimDataDictionary release];
_tutorialAnimDataDictionary = nil;
[super dealloc];
```

By checking other related questions, I have seen people complaining about the similar bugs but nobody really gets the answer and knows why it happens.

I have tons of leaks related to this code and I feel it is essential to kill it.

Thanks!

Comment: I suspect that you aren't using automatic reference counting.  Is that right?  If so, why don't you have automatic reference counting enabled?

Comment: Just made the changes by adding dealloc functions on the questions. Yes, you are right, I am not using ARC cause it is an old and also my first ios project. I decide to not use ARC so that I can practice memory management of iOS.

Comment: I edited my comment.  I realized after I posted my original comment that it's not `_animDataDictionary` or `_tutorialAnimDataDictionary` that's leaking.  It's the path and tutorialPath dictionaries that are leaking.  Incidentally, you don't need to set those variables to nil in your dealloc method.  Lots of people do that, it's kind of a viral anti-pattern that's spread around, but if anything is trying to get at your object's ivars after the object has been deallocated then you've got bigger problems than whether or not the ivars are nilled out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like you're leaking your NSDictionary objects, as the static analyzer indicated.  You aren't storing the result of `[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path]` or of `[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:tutorialPath]` anywhere so you can't send those objects explicit release messages.

Try adding autorelease calls after creating those intermediate dictionaries, like:

```
_animDataDictionary = [[[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path] autorelease] objectForKey:@"frames"];
_tutorialAnimDataDictionary = [[[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:tutorialPath] autorelease] objectForKey:@"frames"];
```

Comment: +1 That is correct. An alternative (and slightly more readable version) would be `[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path]`

Comment: @zeroliu, @Alladinian: Yea, actually using `[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:]` is probably the way to go here.  It works just like `[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:<path>] autorelease]` but is more readable as @Alladinian noted.

Answer (score 0):

first: are you sure that your dealloc method is called?
add a NSLog in it to be sure that your class is deallocated.
If not, the problem is not inside the code of that class, but in the code of the class that use (allocated/created) it.

second, the method where you alloc your dictionaries is called just once? or you may call these lines more times:

```
_animDataDictionary = [[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path] objectForKey:@"frames"];
_tutorialAnimDataDictionary = [[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:tutorialPath] objectForKey:@"frames"];
```

in this last case you need to release the 2 dictionaries before you create new ones:

```
[_animDataDictionary release]; // the first time it's = nil, and calling this line has no problem anyway
_animDataDictionary = [[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path] objectForKey:@"frames"];
[_tutorialAnimDataDictionary release];
_tutorialAnimDataDictionary = [[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:tutorialPath] objectForKey:@"frames"];
```